# How to Replace the value in particular key in LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, collections

I want to replace the value in particular key in LinkedHashMap.

for example 
The initial Condition..

```
"key1" -> "value1"
"key2" -> "value2"
"key3" -> "value3"
"key4" -> "value4"
"key5" -> "value5"
```

I want to expected result...

```
"key1" -> "value1"
"key2" -> "value8"
"key3" -> "value3"
"key4" -> "value6"
"key5" -> "value5"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You put a new value for that key :

```
map.put("key2","value8");
map.put("key4","value6");
```

Note that for `LinkedHashMap`, changing the value for an existing key won't change the iteration order of the `Map` (which is the order in which the keys were first inserted to the Map).

Comment: Actually you can choose whether you want the LinkedHashMap iteration in insertion-order or access-order

Comment: @lbalazscs Oh, you're right. Insertion order is the default, but there's a constructor that allows you to override this default.

Answer (score 3):

In Map(LinkedHashMap) key is the unique value. So whenever you try to put  a value for a key, it will either add new entry in map or if key already exist then it will replace old value for that key with new value.

```
map.put("existing key", "new value");
```

Above code will replace value of `existing key` in map with `new value`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of checking if the key is present or not:

```
  if (map.containsKey(key)) {
      map.put("existing key", "newValue");
  }
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking to check if a key is present. Using a put will either add if it's not there, or replace if a key is there. There's no need to check if a key exists beforehand for this.